# Python - SQLAlchemy Engine cannot connect

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am using sqlalchemy and pyodbc to connect to my SQL Server.

```
pyodbc version == 4.0.30
sqlalchemy version == 1.4.19
```

This used to work fine in the past but it just stop working giving me the following error:

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

This is the code that I am using:

```
sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://{SERVER NAME}/{DB NAME}?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes'
                                     ).connect()
```

As I said this used to work perfectly but it just stopped.

Any ideas why that might be the case and how I can trace back to what is causing the above error?

Really would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: You need to add `?driver=…` to the end of your connection URL as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections)

Comment: If you mean {driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server}, this does not work either

Comment: Try `&Trusted_Connection=yes` (ampersand instead of question mark).